# Is there a way to use reportviewer 9 in Visual Studio 2010 and still have rdlc designer support?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, reportviewer

I've got an annoying problem here. I've recently upgraded to VS 2010. I really like VS-2010 and I want to keep using it. However I ran into a problem. When I tried to open the rdlc files it bitched at me that my RDLC report files were the old version (used the vs2008 rdlc files) and it had to upgrade them to the new version to support the new report designer. After I did this reportviewer 9 was complaining it couldn't use these files, so I had to "upgrade" to reportviewer 10 which I've found is a complete piece of trash. It's so slow in rendering its pretty much useless to me.

I really need a way to continue to use reportviewer 9 and VS 2010 and still have designer support. Can I open rdlc files individually with vs2008? Has anybody been fighting with reportviewer 10 lately?

Alternatively if someone knows a magic fix to make reportviewer 10 render reports as fast as 9 I'd accept that as an answer as well.

Isaac

Comment: One workaround I've found is to just keep the old files but open them individually in vs 2008 to edit them. VS2010 should have retained designer support for old rdlc files. Shame on microsoft.

Comment: A year later, I've grown to like reportviewer 10. Either the service pack improved it a lot or I'm just crazy. Anyway, now all but one of my reports run flawlessly on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it was the service pack or if I was originally crazy, but nowadays reportviewer 10 seems very reasonable. The ability of it to render html like tags is very useful to me. Only one report I made that uses subreports heavily is having a hard time rendering quickly. I would suggest to anyone stuck on reportviewer 9 to bite the bullet and upgrade as many reports as they can. For the old ones, you can still edit them in VS2008 although you are in for some manual xml editing to get the data properties set up and what not.

Comment: also solved my subreport problem now too, now I can throw reportviewer 9 in the trash bin.